# cant setText of EditText inside MediaPipe addPacketCallback

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, processor, mediapipe

I am using `MediaPipe` in Android to get the output from the graph, and set that output as `EditText`'s text. Following is the code:

```
editText.setText("hello world".toString());
 processor.addPacketCallback(
          OUTPUT_STREAM_NAME,
          (packet) -> {
              String output = PacketGetter.getString(packet);
                  editText.setText("hello world 1".toString());
                  //editText.setText(output.toString());
              Log.d(TAG,"[TS:" + packet.getTimestamp() + " : " + ouput);
          });
```

The `setText()` outside the callback works fine, but inside the callback is never set and whenever I try to select the the `EditText` following exception occurs:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0
```

Comment: Try this check `if (output !=null && !output.isEmpty()) { editText.setText(output.toString())}`

Comment: it gives exception when i set "hello world 1" , i have not even tested the output yet, i am just setting a static text.

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is odd with `editText.setText("hello world 1".toString())` .. Do you limit the length of the `EditText` to some value less that that?

Comment: No, also outside processor.addPacketCallback, the setText works fine.

Comment: "hello world" is String, why do you want toString()?

Comment: @hungcuiga1 was just testing out. Without toString() same exception.

Comment: Last thing but not releted to the exception   run this explicitly in UI thread  `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                editText.setText("hello world 1") 
            }
        });`

Comment: @Zain runOnUiThread works fine and sets the text.

Comment: @Klaffy Good job .. I posted this as an answer so it might help visitors in the future .. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that `addPacketCallback()` called on a worker thread, and changing UI there requires to explicitly run it on UI thread

```
editText.setText("hello world".toString());
processor.addPacketCallback(
        OUTPUT_STREAM_NAME,
        (packet) -> {
            String output = PacketGetter.getString(packet);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    editText.setText("hello world 1");
                }
            });
            //editText.setText(output.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "[TS:" + packet.getTimestamp() + " : " + ouput);
        });
```